# Unable to connect to database - MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to connect to my database using the code below:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($address, $username, $password, $database, $port);

if (!$connection) {
    throw new Exception("Error: Unable to connect to MySQL (Error Code " . mysqli_connect_errno() . ": " . mysqli_connect_error() . ")");
}
```

I've checked that all the variables are correct, but still I can't connect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: `show variables like '%timeout%';` in particular `wait_` whatcha got and who is your shared hoster?

Comment: Error Code 2006 - MySQL server has gone awa

Comment: The wait timeout is 28800. Namecheap is the provider

Comment: check out [what the manual says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html) . namecheap is fun to use btw

Comment: Nothing in the manual seems to be relevant except for this: "It is also possible to see this error if host name lookups fail (for example, if the DNS server on which your server or network relies goes down)". I have no idea how to determine if this is the issue

Comment: are you having success in general with your code or no where. Bring it back up to 50k feet. Depending on that, I could test some stuff if you gave it all (all empty of course) so I could test it against a namecheap acct I have

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems with this and it turned out it was the password settings for the connecting user.

It appears that the default authentication type for MySQL 5.7 is to set the password to be SHA256 hashed vs. the older method.

This works fine on MySQL cli but not via PHP 7.2.x (the latest).

There's a bug logged with the PHP team here:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76651

It seems that PHP has a way to go before supporting some of the newer higher security settings that the later versions of MySQL support.